# Django annotate to return other fields as well

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class ModelTest(models.Model):
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test_field = models.IntegerField()
    test_date = models.DateTimeField()
    test_make = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, I want rows which have **max test_date** for the **same test_field**.

What I did was `ModelTest.objects.values('test_field').annotate(td=Max('test_date')).values('test_field','test_date')`.

Now, I want that I get all the other field values as well for the selected rows. If I try adding them in any of the `values`, the annotate doesn't work.

What is the possible solution?

**UPDATE :**

Test Data:

```
test_name | test_field | test_date                     | test_make

test1     | 1          | 2012-01-23 15:24:10.389+05:30 | 3

test2     | 2          | 2012-01-23 15:24:26.747+05:30 | 5

test3     | 3          | 2012-01-23 15:27:19.033+05:30 | 1

test4     | 2          | 2012-01-23 15:29:45.098+05:30 | 4

test5     | 3          | 2012-01-23 15:54:01.322+05:30 | 2
```

Now, I want as output is:

```
test1     | 1          | 2012-01-23 15:24:10.389+05:30 | 3

test4     | 2          | 2012-01-23 15:29:45.098+05:30 | 4

test5     | 3          | 2012-01-23 15:54:01.322+05:30 | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
[ModelTest.objects.get(test_field=x['test_field'],test_date=x['td'])
     for x in ModelTest.objects.values('test_field').annotate(td=Max('test_date'))
]
```

Since your annotation is returning only the fields you want, there will be only one combination of `test_field` + `test_date` that matches your result.

Annotate doesn't return any objects, only list of matches which are dicts, so you have to again query your objects.

A better approach would be to write your own custom query and use it with [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't give the `**max test_date** for the **same test_field**`. Basically, it doesn't find anything to annotate on.

Comment: Hey Burhan, This way is fine. But, is it possible to make a single Django query?

Comment: You can do that, by with custom SQL in `extra`

Comment: Will this be efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if I'm understanding you, but if you refer to the Django guide here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

To return an aggregation queryset that has an entire row where some criteria meets the aggregation clause, you just write: ModelTest.objects.all().annotate(td=Max('test_date')). Strictly speaking, this will give you more than one row if max('test_date') occurs more than once in the table.

If you first need to filter the query set, you can do that instead of using the all() you can use filter(criteria_here) and chain them like you would any other queryset.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get an output from that. Please see the output that I require in the update.